# How can i change another program icon?

Tags: c++, windows, icons

How can i change another program icon(not mine) in C++ ? I want to do this on Windows. One of my friend is programming in VB and he made a program that can change another .exe icon. So how can i do that in C++ ?

Comment: You could right click the shortcut choose Properties then click the change icon button ...

Comment: Do you want to change the icon resource stored in the executable or change the icon that Explorer uses when it shows the file?  Changing the executable may require admin privileges if the .exe is installed to a protected location (e.g., Program Files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After preparing your updated resource (using LoadIcon/LoadImage, depending on where your icon is stored), go through the steps to call UpdateResource:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

The documentation for the functions should cover the finer points of what you might need to do.

Comment: Not quite. GetModuleHandle plays not part. Call BeginUpdateResource, UpdateResource and finally EndUpdateResource.